# AWS online Development endpoint throws importerror no module named aws glue.transforms

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to run a ETL job in AWS glue using python the script is

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

person = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
           database="test",
           table_name="testetl_person")

person.printSchema()
```

This script is running in AWS development endpoint and on running the job throws the below exception

```
File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 118, in <module>
runpy.run_path(temp_file_path, run_name='__main__')
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-cf4xyag5/test.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglue.transforms'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 137, in <module>
raise e_type(e_value).with_tracsback(new_stack)
AttributeError: 'ModuleNotFoundError' object has no attribute 'with_tracsback'
```

Can anyone help me out?
If you require further information do let me know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [This](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-cloudfront-log-analysis/issues/2), Your language to run the code should set as spark, not python.

Comment: well i checked and its type is set to python.

Comment: that is problem. Set it to `spark`

Comment: Hey guys, where do you find this Spark/Python setting "language to run the code"? I have the same problem trying to run a python script in IntelliJ



        `from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions 
\
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awsglue'`

Comment: @Rimer Did you find the problem? I have the same issue with InteliJ

Comment: Unfortunately no, never found solution, and am no longer on the project :(

Comment: From here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-pycharm.html point 7: In the Interpreter field, change the path to /usr/bin/gluepython if you are using Python 2, or to /usr/bin/gluepython3 if you are using Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running spark using the Glue development endpoint on a sagemaker notebook, it could be a permissions issue as highlighted in this aws forums [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=938221)

The Glue development endpoint needs the following IAM policy to download the required awsglue [library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs) from an S3 bucket provided by AWS.

```
arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceNotebookRole
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you selected a `python` notebook instead of a `pyspark` notebook.

You have to select a `pyspark` notebook.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% about this

One possible solution is:

1. 1. Delete your dev endpoint
2. 2. Add AWSGlueServiceRole to the role you will create a new endpoint with
3. 3. Create a new dev endpoint

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what happened,but I solve this problem by not setting vpn. You can create everything following the link:https://aws-dojo.com/ws8/labs/developer-endpoint/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30400828)